# React having to double-click

Tags: reactjs

I am currently working on a complex ReactJS project and have encountered an issue. I am sharing the reduced version of the problem I have identified.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
  const [text, setText] = useState(null);

  const addText = (word) => {
    setText(word);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getLocation = (e) => {
      const targetClassList = e.target.classList;
      if (targetClassList.contains("click-btn")) {
        setClicked(true);
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("click", getLocation);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", getLocation);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div>{text ? text : "Any?"}</div>
        <div
          onClick={clicked ? () => addText("Hello World") : null}
          className="click-btn"
        >
          Click me
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What I want is, if the classlist contains 'click-btn' after the first click, I want the click to work directly and add the text. However, it doesn't happen on the first click, and the text changes only on the second click.

Comment: Can you call `addText("Hello World")` after `setClicked(true)`?

Comment: The issue was indeed caused by that, yes. I have fixed it. Thank you for the comment.